# Call Multiple ViewController with UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my project I have tableView with 10 cells. And in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` all cells have multiple ViewController (files) so, my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` looks like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(indexPath.row == 0) {

            CallViewController *viewc = [[CallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewc animated:YES];
        }else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
            BirthdayViewController *viewc = [[BirthdayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BirthdayViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewc animated:YES];
        }
```

so I don't want these conditions 
I want my code be clean

Comment: how about switch-case.. . it will look clean but will effectively be the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your underlying data model for tableview? If you could add additional attribute as ViewController Class Name you could do something like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDictionary *row = [rowData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Class viewControllerClass =
    NSClassFromString([row objectForKey:@"viewControllerClassName"]);

//Default VC init looks for nib file named as VC afaik, if not, you could
    //add another attribute with init selector name
UIViewController *viewController =
    [[viewControllerClass alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to have an array that contains the `Class` object of your class and then create object and push like

```
//view did load

mutableArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArr addObject:[CallViewController class]];
[mutableArr addObject:[BirthdayViewController class]];
....
....
```

Then in your

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.row < [mutableArr count]) {
       Class *obj = [mutableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       UIViewController *controller = [[objc alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(obj) bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
   }
}
```

---

OR if this is looking more weird then you can do like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UIViewController *controller = nil;
   switch(indexPath.row) {
       case 0:
          controller = [[CallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallViewController" bundle:nil];
          break;
       case 1;
          controller = [[BirthdayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BirthdayViewController " bundle:nil];
          break;
   }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of strings corresponding to file names and use NSClassFromString function to allocate view controllers

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"VC1", @"VC2", @"VC3", nil];
id viewController = [[NSClassFromString([viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) alloc] initWithNibName:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

Add all your classes to NSArray, and select the correct class by the indexPath.row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSArray * conrollersClasses =@[[CallViewController class],[BirthdayViewController class]];
      UIViewController *controller = [[conrollersClasses[indexPath.row] alloc] init];
      [[self navigationController] controller animated:YES];

}
```